# Can I add a custom synchronous meta channel to H264 or VP8?

Tags: video, web, html5-video, video-codecs

I am new to video codec specs, so maybe this a noob question :)

I want to encode frame synchronous meta data with a web video. Is there a standard way with H264/265 OR VP8 to do that? What do I have to Google for?

If not, can I use off screen annotations somehow? So encode the info into certain unshown pixels? Will this technique survive encoding?

Thanks for all hints!

Comment: What is the goal you want to achieve? Obtain the meta data in your playback code? H.264/H.265 have SEI NAL units that are designed to carry meta data, but the HTML5 video element will not expose them to you. I'd say that you need another communication channel (server sent events in js?) that sends the meta data with timings and then you could sync them with the playback through the `ontimeupdate ` callback of the HTML5 video player.

Comment: I actually want to annotate a video stream with data that can be evaluated for support of the playback experience. Therefore it needs to be in sync with the video. I want to avoid sending basically two streams and sync them on client side, as you suggested. It is a valid approach, but would mean a quite complex setup for a quite simple issue ;)